# Determine file type

Tags: file

I managed to recover some files from a lost back-up but without extension. Opening the file in a "text" editor doesn't provide any hint of what type of file it is.

I've uploaded a file [here](http://cl.ly/1f3p241I2F1F363F2k3C).

If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated.

ps. I know it's not a real "programming question" but I suppose this is the best place to ask

Comment: I guess, http://superuser.com/ is more suitable for such question, though it would be better in form "how can I determine filetype" rather than "determine filetype for me, plz". BTW, `file` utility on my linux box was unable to determine the type of your file, so it is either some not widely used binary format, or just garbage.

Comment: Sorry for the tone, you're right. I tried the "file" utility but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a binary file without confidence by running `chardet` command:

```
$ chardet Recovered004
Recovered004: None (confidence: 0.00)
```

These is no magic string in the header by running `file` command:

```
$ file Recovered004
Recovered004: data
```

It can be any unknown binary formatted data.

Comment: pretty much the same thing I got ..bummer :(